# Android programmatically set content description for WebView

Tags: android, data-binding, webview, accessibility, talkback

How to set content description for a WebView used only to play inline videos?
I my app, I am using a WebView to load and play Youtube videos. I have set the content description for the WebView in the XML layout but the talkback only speaks "YouTube WebView".
I have tried setting it via java code but it still reads "YouTube WebView".
How can I programmatically make TalkBack speak out the content I require?

XML code:

```
<WebView
     android:id="@+id/video"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:contentDescription="YOUTUBE VIDEO TEXT TO READ DURING TALKBACK"
     android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
     android:setYouTubeUrl="@{YouTubeURL}"
     app:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
```

BindingAdapter code:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:setYouTubeUrl"})
    public static void setYouTubeUrl(WebView webView, String url) {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // required to view video
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

URL eg:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXX